How to custom format a number in T-SQL
If I use this custom mask to format a number in SQL Server, I see that it ignores all but the decimal mask and does it's own thing (which I believe might have something to do with the regional settings of the SQL Server):
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'#,##,#0.00' );

Results in: 123,456,789.12 instead of  1,23,45,67,89.12
To FORCE a custom mask, I've been able to figure out that I need to escape the comma and period like this:
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'#\,##\,#0.00' )

But that results in: 12345,67,89.12 instead of  1,23,45,67,89.12.
So I need to do a rather elaborate script to first figure out the length of the numbers, then build a complete mask like this:
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'##\,##\,##\,##\,#0.00' )

Which then correctly displays: 1,23,45,67,89.12
Simply building a mask like this won't work:
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,#0.00' )

Because it results in this: ,,,,,1,23,45,67,89.12
Is there an easier way to do this?  The reason we need this is for two reasons:

Some countries are 1,234.56 while others are 1.234,56
Some countries have seperators in different places like 1,23,456.78

I know that I can apply culture like this:
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'#,#0.00', N'en-US' ), FORMAT( @Number, N'#,#0.00', N'hi-IN' )

Which results in 123,456,789.12 and 12,34,56,789.12, but customers want control over the separation characters, like making them spaces, or swopping the comma and period around, etc.
I know that I can roll a complete custom solution, but I wanted to find out whether there was a better approach?  I've searched high and low, but couldn't find anything better than a completely custom solution.
Looking forward to your insights.

This should not be done in your database, the format function is fairly slow and will have a great impact on query performance depending on the amount of data you are working with. Handle the formatting in the client application instead. In the client application you can take advantage of local regional settings of the machine that is running the app.

Can you not restrict your customers to selecting from cultures that are actually in existence? Plus potentially an optional replacement of the thousands separator with a space? India uses 12,34,56,789.12 as shown in the Q does any culture actually use 1,23,45,67,89.12?

Wait, are you expecting # to mask the value when using FORMAT; so # means a literal '#' character? No, that is not what # means. FORMAT invokes CLR and uses the .Net formatting rules, and in that # means a digit placeholder. Likewise, \# means a literal #, not replace a character with #.

I started to write something "clever" using REPLICATE-function and the length of the integer part of the number, but realized this is just a waste of cycles to do in SQL. But feel free to play around with it

@siggemannen, I also tried using an expression as second parameter of the FORMAT function. Something like SELECT @number, FORMAT( @number, REPLICATE('##\,', (LEN(CONVERT(int, @number/100)) + 1) / 2) + '#0.00'). Seems like a possible solution.

@Zhorov Using LOG is probably better than messing with string lengths CONVERT(int, LOG(@Number, 10))

Gotta watch out with negative numbers for LOG though

Thanks for the input everyone, glad to see I wasn't wrong when finding that the solution wasn't trivial.  I've come up with the below solution, would appreciate any insights into how it may be improved.
I can see that my solution matches some of your input, so at least I'm happy to see that I was on the right track.
I tried it on a million records and it's performance was more than acceptable.  I hear all of you when you say this doesn't belong in the database, but they have valid reasons why they require it there; at the end of the day, the customer gets what the customer wants right? :)
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = -123456789.9876543;
DECLARE @Group1Digits tinyint = 3;
DECLARE @Group2Digits tinyint = 2;
DECLARE @GroupSymbol nvarchar(2) = N' ';
DECLARE @DecimalSymbol nvarchar(2) = N'-';
DECLARE @DecimalDigits tinyint = 3;

SELECT [Source number] = @Number
    , [Integer part] = ROUND( ABS( @Number ), 0, 1 )
    , [Decimal part] = ABS( @Number ) % 1
    , [Mask] = CONCAT( 
        N'#'
        , @GroupSymbol
        , REPLICATE( N'#', ISNULL( @Group2Digits, @Group1Digits ) )
        , @GroupSymbol
        , REPLICATE( N'#', @Group1Digits - 1 ), N'0'
        , @DecimalSymbol
        , REPLICATE( N'0', @DecimalDigits )
    )

    -- Solution:
    , [Formatted number] = CONCAT( 
        -- 1. Check for a sign and apply it.
        IIF( @Number < 0, N'-', N'' )

        -- 2. Get the integer part as a positive integer.
        , LTRIM( FORMAT( ROUND( ABS( @Number ), 0, 1 ),
            CONCAT( 
                -- 3. Build the secondary part of the mask, supporting cultures like India that use a unique "dual" design like #,##,###
                --  We just replicate by log base 10 (length) of the integer, which is sufficient to achieve an "apprixmation" mask, we'll be trimming off the excess at the end.
                REPLICATE( CONCAT( REPLICATE( N'#', ISNULL( @Group2Digits, @Group1Digits ) ), IIF( @GroupSymbol IN ( N'.', N',' ), CONCAT( N'\', @GroupSymbol ), @GroupSymbol ) ), LOG( ABS( @Number ), 10 ) )
                -- 4. Build the primary part of the mask, e.g. ##0
                , REPLICATE( N'#', @Group1Digits - 1 ), N'0'
            )
        -- 5. Trim off the excess mask.
        ), @GroupSymbol )

        -- 6. Add the decimal symbol.
        , @DecimalSymbol
        -- 7. Format the decimal part of the number.
        , SUBSTRING( FORMAT( ABS( @Number ) % 1, CONCAT( N'.', REPLICATE( N'0', @DecimalDigits ) ), N'en-US' ), 2, @DecimalDigits )
    )
;




Source number
Integer part
Decimal part
Mask
Formatted number




-123456789.98765
123456789.00000
0.98765
# ## ##0-000
-12 34 56 789-988




The FORMAT function uses .NET to format the string. In .NET you can use a custom culture with a specified NumberGroupSizes of [2], but in SQL Server you can only specify a standard culture.
On my machine there is no such culture, the only cultures that do not have [3] as the NumberGroupSizes are Indian ones, which all have [3, 2]. For example, you could use hi for Hindi:
DECLARE @Number numeric(20, 5) = 123456789.123;
SELECT @Number, FORMAT( @Number, N'#,##,#0.00', 'hi' );










123456789.12300
12,34,56,789.12



db<>fiddle
Your only other options are:

Try to set a custom culture on the operating system itself.
Use SQLCLR to call into .NET directly.
Do some kind of custom formatting like you are already doing. You can use CONVERT(int, LOG(@Number, 10)) to calulate how many digits it is.
Just use concatenation manually with some modulo arithmetic.


Thanks for input, I'm going to try use the SQLCLR in the future to hopefully increase the performance of my below solution.  But for now, it seems to do the trick.
